# How to deal with a recursive aggregation in postgresql

Tags: postgresql, view, aggregate-functions, common-table-expression, recursive-query

I am trying to represent a hierarchy of values and weights so that each node is getting computed by his child's values according to their weights. Each node has weight but only the leaves have values that stored in another table and each parent node's value is the weighted average of his children. I want to write a view that will recursively compute the values of all the nodes in the hierarchy.

Tables:

nodes - id,parent_id

values - id,value,node_id

weights - id,weight,node_id